# Persistant white background though I have set it to clear

Tags: ios, background, transparent

I've got a GridViewCell and am setting the background of it to clearColor like so:

```
UIView* mainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 123)];
[mainView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Though for some reason, the background remains white.

This is what I'm seeing:

[image]

If it's any help, I'm following [this tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/design-build-a-small-business-app-aqgridview/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error, I figured out that in my cellForItemAtIndex method, I needed to set the backgkround color of that *cell* to clear like so:

```
[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure what you're seeing is the `window`.

In your App Delegate:

`[self.window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];`

and you should be seeing all red.

Comment: If you're using IB, you can also change the `backgroundColor` for the `window` there.

Comment: Hmm, it had no effect. I've put an image on for you to see.